# Android Can't Install my App, ported from Eclipse to Android Studio, on my test phone, a Pixel XL

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, installation

I've been maintaining an app for a friend's company for several years. When they recently updated from Android 5 to Android 7, the app stopped working. So I ported to Android Studio and started fixing stuff. Now, after squashing a bunch of bugs, I can't get the app to install on my test phone, which is a Pixel XL running Android 8. It was running debug images until I uninstalled it so I could test the install. (I think that was because of Instant Run.)

Now I get the following:

```
$ adb install-multiple -r -t I:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk I:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk I:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk I:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk I:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk I:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk I:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk I:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk I:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk I:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk I:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk I:\Users\...\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed

$ adb shell am start -n "com.pbs.deliverytrack1/com.pbs.deliverytrack1.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
    Error while executing: am start -n "com.pbs.deliverytrack1/com.pbs.deliverytrack1.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
    Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.pbs.deliverytrack1/.MainActivity }
    Error type 3
    Error: Activity class {com.pbs.deliverytrack1/com.pbs.deliverytrack1.MainActivity} does not exist.

    Error while Launching activity
```

**Does com.pbs.deliverytrack1/com.pbs.deliverytrack1.MainActivity look correct?**

**ADDITIONAL NOTES:**
I was able to get the apk to install over email on a Samsung Edge 7.0 running Nougat 7.0. I'm still unable to get it to install on my Google Pixel XL which is running Oreo 8.0.

I've tried about every combination of build versions I can think of. The key, I think is in the error message:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.pbs.deliverytrack1/com.pbs.deliverytrack1.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Error while executing: am start -n "com.pbs.deliverytrack1/com.pbs.deliverytrack1.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.pbs.deliverytrack1/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.pbs.deliverytrack1/com.pbs.deliverytrack1.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

In the section that says: cmp=com.pbs.deliverytrack1/.MainActivity, should that be com.pbs.deliverytrack1/com.pbs.deliverytrack1.MainActivity?

**UPDATE**
After messing around with the minSDK, maxSDK, and targetSDK, as well as three different versions of Android: 7.0, 7.1.1, and 8.0, I've found a way to continue working. My client is using 7.0 and 7.1.1, so I built an emulator running 7.0 that I've been using to debug my application. (My wife's suggestion, actually.) So I'm moving forward again.

I'm also going to do what I usually do when dealing with freaky problems. I'm going to go through with -XLint and fix every warning I can find. (When you can't fix the bug you want, baby, fix the bug you got.) Besides cleaning up some long outstanding problems, I'm hoping it will eventually lead to the squashing of this bug.

Thank you to everyone for the help and suggestions. I'll leave this open for a bit, to see if someone comes up with a miracle. I'd prefer to award the bounty than just let it go into the bit bucket. :)

So, once again, I humbly ask for help.  Thanks, Ray

Comment: According to the errors, you are able to install the app. What you're not able to do is start this activity, as the activity cannot be found. Does the launcher icon work? Can you run it directly from the IDE?

Comment: The launcher icon is gone and hasn't returned. When I try to install from email, that install fails, but it doesn't say why. Since I uninstalled the app from the phone, I can no longer run it on the phone from the IDE.

Comment: "The launcher icon is gone and hasn't returned" -- then probably the whole activity is gone, including its manifest entry. "I can no longer run it on the phone from the IDE" -- what are your symptoms when you run it from the IDE?

Comment: Did you tried just to disable `Instant run` in settings ?

Comment: I did try disabling instant run in android studio. Is there someplace else I should look?

Comment: The symptoms when trying to run from the IDE are the ones first given. I haven't tried running on emulator,  because I find that doesn't help as much as on the phone.

Comment: What is weird is that when trying to run from the IDE, it does say the split APKs are installed, but there's no icon on the phone and I can't start the application from the IDE.

Is there any more information I can give you that can help solve this problem? I'm at the point where I'm trying random stuff, which is never good.

Comment: There is a lot of good information in the various answers that have been given. None has yet solved the problem, but I have been able to get things working for Nougat. I do have the app ported to Android Studio, so now I'm going to go fix every lint warning and anything else I can find. Then I'll return to this problem. I've often found that if I can't fix a problem, refactoring like crazy and fixing warnings often helps.

Answer (score 7):

Like CommonsWare mentioned in the comment, it looks like your app is installing, it's just unable to be started. I can think of two things to check on:

1. Make sure your `AndroidManifest.xml` file lists the correct fully qualified class name of the `MainActivity`. If it's incorrect, then your app will install, but it will crash when starting and complain about not being able to find your `MainActivity`.
2. If you're using ProGuard, check to make sure your rules are set up so that ProGuard isn't stripping the `MainActivity` class from your APK. Many developers only ProGuard their non-debug builds and you mentioned your debug builds work fine, so that might be a hint.
3. EDIT: I can think of one more. If you're changing the `applicationId` in your `debug` `buildType`, then you'd need to specify the same ID in your `adb am start` command.

Comment: I'm not using proguard on either apk at this time. Here's the activity part of the AndroidManifest.xml
    <activity
            android:name="com.pbs.deliverytrack1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Looks correct to me, just like everything else does. I just added a #3 above, check that out.

Comment: I'll double check the application id, but even if it had changed, shouldn't it work if I'd uninstalled the app on the phone?

Comment: Nothing has changed on the application id. We have determined that the app can be installed via email on 7.0 and 7.1.1, but not on 8.0 of Android. On 8.0, it says installation failed if you try to install from email, but, as above, it says the split APKS were installed, if installing via IDE.

Comment: Beats me, then... sorry! Wish I had the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If nothing works, try just creating a new project in Android Studio, with all the proper info (such as same package name, compatibilty with Android Devices), when creating the first activity, copy all of the content in your Java and XML Layout files from the old project. Create another activity (for example, if you had a `DrawerActivity` in your Eclipse project, create another DrawerActivity in Android Studio. This hopefully might work.

**I'm not sure if this will work, but it *is* the easier option.** 
First, copy everything from your old project's `Resources` folder, copy all the Java files to to the new project, and since the `Activities` need to be defined, copy your `AndroidManifest.xml` to your new app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm sure this would work, but it would be a ton of work. When I tried making something like this work before I failed miserably. I have found a work-around for my problem, though eventually I may wind up following your suggestion if my client suddenly decides to upgrade to Oreo.

Comment: If I am correct, Eclipse Android Projects should use the same structure as Android Studio, right? You could copy everything under the `app/src` folder and the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Now there are lot of changes in Android and also in `Android-8`, `Android-7.1` and `Android-7`

So there are lot of new things in it if you are using background service than you have to add extra `Job scheduling` for Android 7,7.1,8

[Nougat Behavior change](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html)

[Oreo Behavior change](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html)

Update Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1

You can Change Module app 
Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.package"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

To Support Emulator

Update the Sdk Android-7,7.1,8. for creating local emulator
**File Menu -> Setting -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Setting -> Android Sdk**

Comment: I think one of the keys is that this problem doesn't happen under 7.0 or 7.1, only 8. I'm going to go over all the Oreo changes and see if I can find something relevant.

Comment: Thanks @Rben, Ok, U may need to check the location and background service limitation in the oreo.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest below points:
1) As already suggested in some of the above comments, I hope you have already Disabled "Instant Run" (Open the Settings or Preferences dialog. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run & Un-check the box next to Enable Instant Run)
2) In AS, Go to File->invalidate cache and restart
3) Pls try Gradle Clean & then Build (app level, from the Right side Gradle Menu Options)

& can u pls tell which Android Studio Version r u currently Using?

Comment: I'm running Android Studio 3.0. I've tried Gradle Clean and then Build. I'll try invalidating the cache to see if that makes a difference.